# COPY command slow from go

Tags: postgresql, go

- HDD,
- Default postgresql config file
- No other connections.

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."ParamValueBlock" (
  "ParameterId" int2 NOT NULL,
  "DeviceId" int2 NOT NULL,
  "CompressedData" bytea,
  "StartDate" int4 NOT NULL,
  "UncompressedDataBits" int4 NOT NULL
)
```

This is my code for batch copy to database:

```
connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
        "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        host, port, user, password, dbname)
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connectionString)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer db.Close()

tx, err := db.BeginTx(context.Background(), &sql.TxOptions{Isolation: sql.LevelReadCommitted, ReadOnly: false})
if err != nil {
    return err
}

stmt, err := tx.Prepare(`COPY "ParamValueBlock" ("ParameterId", "DeviceId", "CompressedData", "StartDate", "UncompressedDataBits") FROM STDIN;`)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

for _, item := range items{
    _, err := stmt.Exec(
        int16(item.paramID),
        1,
        item.dataBuffer,
        item.secondsSince2015,
        int32(item.uncompressedBitsSize))
    if err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return err
    }
}

err = stmt.Close()
if err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    return err
}

err = tx.Commit()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
return nil
```

I am writing 1000 items (1 item = 28KB) and this is 7 seconds.

Why so slow and how can i optimize this?

If do it is from file:

```
COPY "ParamValueBlock" FROM 'C:\Temp\x.txt' (FORMAT text);
```

time is 0.7 seconds

Profile cpu:

```html
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
     1.82s 31.06% 31.06%      1.83s 31.23%  runtime.cgocall
     0.35s  5.97% 37.03%      0.36s  6.14%  ...pq.appendEscapedText
     0.30s  5.12% 42.15%      0.76s 12.97%  fmt.(*fmt).fmtInteger
     0.30s  5.12% 47.27%      1.53s 26.11%  fmt.(*pp).doPrintf
     0.14s  2.39% 67.92%      2.98s 50.85%  fmt.Sprintf
     0.11s  1.88% 76.11%      0.97s 16.55%  fmt.(*pp).printArg
     0.10s  1.71% 77.82%      0.19s  3.24%  fmt.(*buffer).Write (inline)
     0.09s  1.54% 79.35%      0.85s 14.51%  fmt.(*pp).fmtInteger
     0.09s  1.54% 80.89%      3.26s 55.63%  github.com/lib/pq.encodeBytea
     0.01s  0.17% 94.37%      5.20s 88.74%  github.com/lib/pq.(*copyin).Exec
```

Comment: How do you measure a time spent for copy? Please add time.Since in your program and measure what is taking the most time.

Comment: @AlexPliutau i was add profile output snippet to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pg driver bug: https://github.com/lib/pq/pull/784

I was replace `github.com/lib/pq` to `github.com/jackc/pgx/stdlib` and set this server configuration in `postgresql.conf`:

```
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.0  
autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 5000
autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.0  
autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 5000  
synchronous_commit = off
wal_level = 'minimal'
archive_mode = off
max_wal_senders = 0
```

**And this increase insert speed by 60%**

Additional information

1. use `PREPARE` with `INSERT` or `COPY`
2. `Stmt` must be closed **after** transaction
3. pgx `COPY` is only supported through the native(no stdlib) interface. You can
   use `AcquireConn` and `ReleaseConn` to get a `*pgx.Conn` from the
   database/sql pool.

My sample for inserting many rows:

```html
func InsertParamValueBlocks(params []model.ParamValueBlock) error {
 var dbWrk db.Worker
 var stmt *sql.Stmt
 var err error
 result := dbWrk.DoInTransaction(sql.LevelDefault, func() error {
  stmt, err = dbWrk.Context.Prepare(`INSERT INTO "ParamValueBlock" ("ParameterId", "DeviceId", "CompressedData", "StartDate", "UncompressedDataBits")VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5);`)
  if err != nil {
   return err
  }

  for _, param := range params {
   _, err := stmt.Exec(
    param.ParameterID,
    param.DeviceID,
    param.CompressedData,
    param.StartDate,
    param.UncompressedDataBits)
   if err != nil {
    return err
   }
  }

  return nil
 })
 //stmt close after transaction
 err = stmt.Close()
 if err != nil {
  return err
 }
 return result
}
```